# Concatenate strings in bash while adding double quotes

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following bash script:

```
set -ex
X="bash -c"
Y="ls -al"
```

I want to execute (notice the double quotes):

```
bash -c "ls -al"
```

The following does not work:

```
C=$X\ $Y
$C
```

This gives as output

```
+ X='bash -c'
+ Y='ls -al'
+ C='bash -c ls -al'
+ bash -c ls -al
```

There are no double quotes around ls -al

I tried this:

```
C=$X\ \"$Y\"
```

But that doesn't work:

```
+ X='bash -c'
+ Y='ls -al'
+ C='bash -c "ls -al"'
+ bash -c '"ls' '-al"'
```

How to correctly concatenate Y to X while keeping double quotes around Y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an array variable for `C`:

```
X="bash -c"
Y="ls -al"
C=($X "$Y")
"${C[@]}"
```

Note that `$X` is not quoted since we have one command and one parameter.

Or the short version:

```
C=(bash -c "ls -al")
"${C[@]}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Either of these methods will work, and I'm sure there are more.

```
X="bash -c"
Y="ls -al"

Z="$X \"$Y\""
echo $Z

Z=$(printf '%s "%s"' "$X" "$Y")
echo $Z
```

Comment: How do you execute it?

Comment: @Freddy `echo $Z | sh` works.  Or `eval $Z`.